Missing AUTHENTICATE_ environment variables with authn_dbd and auth_form
I'm experimenting with auth_dbd and auth_form. I'm currently trying to get environment variables of the form AUTHENTICATE_COLUMN created by AuthDBDUserPWQuery as mentionned on apache doc. I noticed that they appear after restarting apache but vanish right after reloading a page.
auth part of my vhost:
<Location "/">
       AuthType form
       AuthName realm
       ErrorDocument 401 "/login.php?%{QUERY_STRING}"

       # To cache credentials, put socache ahead of dbd here
       AuthFormProvider socache dbd

       # Also required for caching: tell the cache to cache dbd lookups!
       AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
       AuthnCacheContext my-server

       # mod_authn_dbd SQL query to authenticate a user
       AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT pwd, first_name, last_name, username, email FROM user WHERE username = %s"
       
       Session On
       SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
       SessionCookieName session path=/
</Location>
<Location "/user">
       # mod_authz_core configuration
       Require valid-user
</Location>

I didn't find much about similar kind of issues and I'm slowly getting familiar with apache stuff.
What am I missing ? Should I do an additional query after login ?
Thank you for your help :)
PS: I'm using Docker image php-apache with mariadb.

Ok so I finally solved it :)
Seems like the problem was coming from caching with shmcb. I switched to memcache and it works fine.
Just replaced to this:
AuthnCacheSOCache memcache:${HTTP_HOST}

